# Jetpack compose PreviewParameter annotaion is not injecting provider class

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to preview my card composeable function which takes a custom parametrs.

My card composeable preview function is not rendered in the preview tab and when trying to deploy the preview into a device the app crashes and by inspecting the log I found that the parameter passed into my card composeable preview is returning null even though it's annotaited with `@PreviewParameter` and passed in a parameter provider class implementing the `PreviewParameterProvider<*>` interface.

I've noticed one line in the log that got my attention:

> D/PreviewActivity: Previewing `PokemonCardPreview` without a parameter provider.
> for some reason my parameter provider class is not being detected by `PreviewActivity`.

`PokemonCardPreview`

```kotlin
@Preview("Pokemon Card")
@Composable
fun PokemonCardPreview(
        @PreviewParameter(PokedexEntryListParameterProvider::class) fakePokedex: PokedexListEntry,
        navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
){
        PokedexEntry(entry = fakePokedex, navController)
}
```

`PokedexEntryListParameterProvider`

```kotlin
class PokedexEntryListParameterProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<PokedexListEntry> {
    override val values = sequenceOf(
        PokedexListEntry(pokemonName = "ditto",
            imageUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/132.png",
            pokemonNumber = 132)
    )

}
```

**Log Error**

```
D/PreviewActivity: Previewing 'PokemonCardPreview' without a parameter provider.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.blacketron.jetpackcomposepokedex, PID: 4987
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Composable Method 'io.blacketron.jetpackcomposepokedex.util.preview.PreviewsKt.PokemonCardPreview' not found
        at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableViaReflection(PreviewUtils.kt:188)
        at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity$setComposableContent$2.invoke(PreviewActivity.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity$setComposableContent$2.invoke(PreviewActivity.kt:73)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:346)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:202)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3433)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2615)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:348)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:702)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:304)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:655)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:719)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            ... 3 more
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableMethod(PreviewUtils.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableViaReflection(PreviewUtils.kt:180)
            ... 61 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter fakePokedex
        at io.blacketron.jetpackcomposepokedex.util.preview.PreviewsKt.PokemonCardPreview(Unknown Source:2)
            ... 64 more
```

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/22644328017dfb36429bdd3e3f992da7) preview works fine to me. Can you check if it works for you both in your project and in a brand new project? I'm using Compose **1.1.0**

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine with Text() composable and after switching back to my PokedexEntry() it worked and the PreviewParameter is detected. Probably it was a bug with android studio or Jetpack compose. Thanks for your help @PhilipDukhov